# how can you write it in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, function

I can't solve this practice help me if you can
it requests to create a function that recives 2 strings then:

1-if strings are same: return 0

2-if by adding or removing only a character from string 1 , it become like string 2 ( means they become same) : return 1 ( adding or removing a character NOT replacing)

3-if part 1 or 2 can't be done: return 2

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can write it to check length.  And see it has differece or not.    But idk how  to check by adding or removing which character first string will be like string two.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on whether this is what you want, but what I have done is:

- If strings are equal return 0
- If we take the longer string and by removing any one character we arrive at the second string, return 1 else return 2

Code for this:

```
def strdiff(s1,s2):
    if(s1==s2):
        return 0
    if(len(s1)>len(s2)):
        for i in range(len(s1)):
            if(s1[0:i]+s1[i+1:len(s1)]==s2):
                return 1
    elif(len(s2)>len(s1)):
        for i in range(len(s2)):
            if(s2[0:i]+s2[i+1:len(s2)]==s1):
                return 1
    else:
        return 2


print(strdiff("asasd","aasd"))
```

Result from this was 1. And seems to follow your questions requirements.